# how i can check if there are a video in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first chrome extension using *JavaScript*. It is required in  it to identify the videos in the page a automatically. And then send  the info. to web service.
 I'm not sure if saving the *URL* and the *video tag* will be a good idea to remember the video.What do you think? is it a good idea? and if it is OK, how i can identify the video tags which inside the page?

Answer (score 0):

Console in google chrome will tell you if your loading things other than just the site.

Right click inspect page, then click console.

Comment: I suppose the OP asks about the technical identification of videos on the page but not the mechanical one.

Comment: You didn't understand the question, i'm talking about "how i can identify the videos that might be flash, HTML5 video.. etc" programmatically from my extension

Comment: if your video is under some form then you can use this document.forms.elements..this will return all the form element and video will be part of it.

Comment: What is a video then?  Do you search for all Canvas tags, and do you define all Canvas tags as Videos?  Are you trying to build something that allows you to find ANYTHING remotely a video?  Some pages have hundreds of flash files that are just ads or small buttons.  What's the purpose?  Or is it better for you to focus on specifics like youtube, veoh, ect...

Comment: The extension is open for all websites, how I can be sure !?

Comment: @Iscariot Ok, What is your idea to make the user identify the video manually ? how i  can implement that thing?

Comment: dotWasim, I get that, I thought you needed to find specific files to put the information into a javascript file, however my follow up was asking at what point do define a video?  Is everything flash and canvas a video?

Comment: No, i need a video( movie, story..etc) to put a translation above it.